# How to write a quicksort partition function

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

This is driving me crazy, I know it's some one-off error causing this, but for some reason, my partition function isn't partitioning correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static int partition(int numbers[], int lhs, int rhs) {
    int pivot = numbers[(rhs - lhs) / 2];
    int lIndex = lhs - 1;
    int rIndex = rhs + 1;

    while (true) {
        while (numbers[++lIndex] < pivot);
        while (numbers[--rIndex] > pivot);

        if (lIndex > rIndex) break;

        int temp = numbers[lIndex];
        numbers[lIndex] = numbers[rIndex];
        numbers[rIndex] = temp;
    }

    return lIndex;
}
```

Comment: heres an example: http://snipd.net/quicksort-in-c

Comment: What measn correct, what means _not correct_?

Comment: Correct means that it returns `lIndex` which should be the correctly placed pivot element. Where everything to the left is less than the pivot, and everything to the right is greater.

Comment: I understand *how* quicksort works. But there is something slightly off about my implementation. Thought that maybe more eyes would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
int pivot = numbers[(rhs - lhs) / 2];
```

Suppose `lhs` = 100 and `rhs` = 120.  The above will choose element (120 - 100) / 2 = 10 as the pivot!

I think you want something like

```
int pivot = numbers[(rhs + lhs) / 2];
```

which will at least choose a pivot from within the range you're trying to partition!

Comment: Broken pivot function for large arrays. The right version is `lhs + (rhs - lhs) / 2` which I'm pretty sure is what he was planning to do in the first place.

Comment: @Voo: That expression will never be more than 1 different than my expression (and in fact it may be identical; I haven't checked the edge cases).

Comment: Oh it's completely identical.. if you ignore overflows. But you really shouldn't if the correct solution is pretty much the same and works in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to find the pivot (mid-point in your case) as :

`int pivot = numbers[lhs + (rhs - lhs) / 2];`

In case, lhs and rhs are high enough, it prevents lhs+rhs from causing an integer overflow.